# Go Struct data identifier/authenticity

Tags: go, hash

How to make a struct with fields and values unique for the data it holds?, The order of fields doesn't matter, what matter is the values of struct's fields must be exactly the same in order to be authenticated/identified.

Currently I used SHA256 hashing method. I hash the struct with the said data. For the next incoming data with same struct, I hash again to verify against previously hashed data to check if it was existed before.

So, let's say:

```
type F struct {
    A string
    B string
    C interface{}
}
```

The value of C can be arbitrary, can be simple types(string, int,etc), map, or struct(e.g. nested json). How to make every data passed to F struct made unique. Have I already doing right using SHA256 on the struct?, I'm worry about the `C` value might affect the value of hash.

Comment: You can hash the json encoding of the struct

Comment: @BurakSerdar the json encoding of the struct would be []byte or string right?, are the keys&vals ordered exactly the same at every attempts?, because if the string has different order of keys/vals inside, the resulting hash would be different right?

Comment: That depends on `C`. If it is a value, struct, or map[string]interface{}, then the ordering would be consistent.

Comment: Note that a struct and map may have the same JSON representation. If that doesn't conform to your definition of identity, JSON encoding doesn't work. The same applies to two different types with identical underlying type.

Comment: I made simple experiment on it to check. And I found it consistent in the ordering. I put json object inside C and I decode json string into the Struct and the interface got replaced with map with consistent ordering.

Comment: @Peter My definition of identity is the structure of the JSON(the order of fields in the same level don't matter, as long as same structure), and the values it holds.